# React and Ionic image share from app to Instagram story

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, instagram

I would like to ask if anyone has experience with sharing images directly to Instagram stories. Is it necessary to use the Instagram API or is there a way to bypass it? I'm using React and Ionic.
I would be grateful for any advice.